# getProduct with id from api, error 400, undefined and bad request

Tags: javascript, request, undefined

```
    getProduct: async ({commit}, id) => {
        const res = await axios.get('https://localhost:44394/api/Products/' + id)
        commit('GET_PRODUCT', res.data)
    },
```

this code doesnt work and it doesnt get the specific product, but if I do like this...

```
    getProduct: async ({commit}) => {
        const res = await axios.get('https://localhost:44394/api/Products/2')
        commit('GET_PRODUCT', res.data)
    },
```

and put a specific id in the link (2 in this case) it works for the product with id 2. How do i get it to get every product from its own id?

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: How about `\`https://localhost:44394/api/Products/${id}\``?

Comment: BTW you should check in the browser inspector window in the Networking tab, if the request is going or not with the proper URL. It may be that requests are going properly, but server side is not proper.

Comment: You should check your network request. 95% chance your ID is not correct.

Comment: calling the function with mapAction and mapGetter

Comment: the network tab tells me the request doesnt get away, error 400, and that its undefined

Comment: When you click on that, do you see a url that you're trying to communicate to? E.g. Request URL: https://localhost:44394/api/Products/...
You sent the request with hardcoded params and it works, when you try it with dynamic ID you get a 400 error, which is a user error, not server. So I'm betting that somewhere along the way the ID got incorrect.

Comment: yes i do, i can get the array with all products not just single them out

Comment: So you're sending an array? You need to filter the ID's and send the one you need. But that should be done before sending the network request. Or you meant that ID's are in array. Best thing would be to just console.log(id) line before sending it via axios call.

Comment: the products in the array has a unik id each and when im getting all of them i can post the id on the page but cand use it to sort products. its there but not there

Answer (score 0):

Check your id is integer and have right id.

call method `getProduct(1)`

if you didn't got 400 error, it is your `id` have problem, not the `getProduction` function.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try `https://localhost:44394/api/Products/${id}`

And you better set up 1 file that store the constant for URL, like

`apiCallUrl.js`

and set the `const URL = https://localhost:44394/`

It'll cleaner for later when your code is bigger, and whenever you want to change the API, you just need to go to there.

Comment: In what scenario would backticks work instead of string concatenation?

Comment: thank you Ill use that cleaner version when im coding bigger, right now im learning javascrip and request things from api, so its a very small code that i try and keep simple so i can follow every step when it goes south :)